# Merge dataframes containing duplicates and null values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, merge

I have a dataframe in the below format:

```
col_1.    col_2.    col_3
null.    null.      yes
null.    null       yes
a1.      a2         no
a3       null       no
```

I would like to add the column "col3" to the below dataframe

```
col1.    col2.  col_1.    col_2.      
a_1      a_2     null.    null.      
a_3      a_4     null.    null      
a_5      a_6     a1.      a2        
a_7      a_8     a3       null
```

Expected output:

```
col1.    col2.  col_1.    col_2.    col_3     
a_1      a_2     null.    null.     yes
a_3      a_4     null.    null      yes
a_5      a_6     a1.      a2        no
a_7      a_8     a3       null      no
```

I tried merging the two dataframes. It did not work as there are duplicate column names.

Comment: are those dots intentional? Do they represent strings `'null.'`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for some kind of implementation of [`eqNullSafe`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe.html).

Inputs:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('null.', 'null.', 'yes'),
     ('null.', None, 'yes'),
     ('a1.', 'a2', 'no'),
     ('a3', None, 'no')],
    ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a_1', 'a_2', 'null.', 'null.'),
     ('a_3', 'a_4', 'null.', None),
     ('a_5', 'a_6', 'a1.', 'a2'),
     ('a_7', 'a_8', 'a3', None)],
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col_1', 'col_2'])
```

Join:

```py
df = df2.join(
    df1,
    df2.col_1.eqNullSafe(df1.col_1) & df2.col_2.eqNullSafe(df1.col_2),
    'left'
).select(df2['*'], df1.col_3)
df.show()
# +----+----+-----+-----+-----+
# |col1|col2|col_1|col_2|col_3|
# +----+----+-----+-----+-----+
# | a_1| a_2|null.|null.|  yes|
# | a_3| a_4|null.| null|  yes|
# | a_7| a_8|   a3| null|   no|
# | a_5| a_6|  a1.|   a2|   no|
# +----+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the extra `(.)` within `null` , hence replaced it with `None` which would be considered as `nulls`

If `nulls` are actual nulls , go ahead with the solution from @ZygD

With the above consideration, the way to merge the dataframes would be with `join` , since you contain special characters , you can escape them with `backtick` and additionally select the required column(s) from each dataframe using `select`

#### Data Preparation

```
s1 = StringIO("""
col_1.,col_2.,col_3
None.,None,yes
None.,None,yes
a1.,a2,no
a3,None,no
"""
)

s2 = StringIO("""
col1.,col2.,col_1.,col_2.
a_1,a_2,None.,None.
a_3,a_4,None.,None  
a_5,a_6,a1.,a2
a_7,a_8,a3,None
"""
)

df1 = pd.read_csv(s1,delimiter=',')

sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(df1)

df2 = pd.read_csv(s2,delimiter=',')

sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(df2)


sparkDF1.show()

+------+------+-----+
|col_1.|col_2.|col_3|
+------+------+-----+
| None.|  None|  yes|
| None.|  None|  yes|
|   a1.|    a2|   no|
|    a3|  None|   no|
+------+------+-----+

sparkDF2.show()

+-----+-----+------+------+
|col1.|col2.|col_1.|col_2.|
+-----+-----+------+------+
|  a_1|  a_2| None.| None.|
|  a_3|  a_4| None.|None  |
|  a_5|  a_6|   a1.|    a2|
|  a_7|  a_8|    a3|  None|
+-----+-----+------+------+
```

#### Join & Select

```
finalDF = sparkDF1.join(sparkDF2
                      ,sparkDF1["`col_1.`"] == sparkDF2["`col_1.`"]
                      ,'inner'
                ).select(
                     sparkDF2['`col1.`']
                    ,sparkDF2['`col2.`']
                    ,sparkDF1['`col_1.`']
                    ,sparkDF1['`col_2.`']
                    ,sparkDF1['col_3']
                )


finalDF.show()

+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|col1.|col2.|col_1.|col_2.|col_3|
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
|  a_1|  a_2| None.|  None|  yes|
|  a_3|  a_4| None.|  None|  yes|
|  a_1|  a_2| None.|  None|  yes|
|  a_3|  a_4| None.|  None|  yes|
|  a_5|  a_6|   a1.|    a2|   no|
|  a_7|  a_8|    a3|  None|   no|
+-----+-----+------+------+-----+
```